# free-jqGrid filterToolbar removes search text after

Tags: jquery, search, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have started using the free-jqGrid available here: https://github.com/free-jqgrid.  I have it working with an old server script that return XML data.  I was using an older version of jqGrid before, and I consider moving to this new free-jqGrid version an upgrade.

The problem I am having is in the filter toolbar.

```
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar');
```

When I fill in the filter toolbar and press ENTER, the server request is made successfully and the filtered data looks like it loads correctly... BUT then the word I just entered in the toolbar is wiped clean.  Previously the word or phrase would stay there, which is the desired action.

I was wondering if there is an option to leave the search phrase in there, or do I need to return a special value from the server?

Thanks!

Here is the web code:

```
<script src="/jqGrid/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/CSS/blue_and_yellow/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="CSS/blue_and_yellow/jquery-ui.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.2/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.2/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>

<h1>Shipping History</h1>
<button id="back_to_shipping_menu">Back to Shipping Menu</button>
<table id="jqGrid"></table>
<div id="jqGridPager"></div>

<style type="text/css">

    .ui-jqgrid-btable {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function($){

    $('#back_to_shipping_menu').button().click(function(){
        window.location.href = "/index.php/operations/production/shipping"
    });

    var lastSel;
    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
        url:'/phpAJAX/Master/master_grid_v1.php',
        postData:{
            'arg1':'new_shipping_history'
        },
        height: 'auto',
        shrinkToFit: true,
        width: Math.floor($(window).width()*.78),
        datatype: 'xml',
        mtype: 'POST',
        colNames:[
            'row_id',
            'Ship Date',
            'Insert/Label',
            'JobNum',
            'Qnty Shipped',
            'Ship_Type',
            'Carrier',
            'Time',
            'Status',
            'Confirm',
            'Date Confirm',
            'Customer'
        ],
        colModel:[
            {width:20,name:'row_id',hidden:true},
            {width:20,name:'ship_date'},
            {width:13,name:'insert_label'},
            {width:13,name:'jobnum'},
            {width:17,name:'Qnty_Shipped', formatter:'number', formatoptions: {decimalSeparator:".", thousandsSeparator: ",", decimalPlaces: 0, defaultValue: "0"}},
            {width:20,name:'Ship_Type', edittype:'select'},
            {width:25,name:'Carrier', edittype:'select'},
            {width:20,name:'Time', edittype:'select'},
            {width:20,name:'Status', edittype:'select'},
            {width:10,name:'Ship_Confirm'},
            {width:20,name:'ship_ts', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s', newformat: 'm/d/Y'}},
            {width:20,name:'Customer'}
        ],
        sortname: 'ship_ts',
        sortorder: 'desc',
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        caption: 'Shipping History',
        rowNum: 20,
        rowList:[20,50,100],
        pager: '#jqGridPager'
    });
    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#jqGridPager', {edit:false,add:false, del: false, search: false, refresh:true});
    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar');

})



</script>
```

Comment: Which version of free jqGrid you use (4.13.2, the latest source from GitHub)? **Could you provide the demo which can be used to reproduce the problem?** Do you have the same problem if the data will be searched locally? (It's much easier to test the problem if it can be reproduce with simple test case without additional communication with the server.). I suppose that one can easy fix the problem by adding `loadFilterDefaults: false`  option of `filterToolbar`, but I would like better to find **the origin** of the problem instead of switching off helpful default `loadFilterDefaults: true`.

Comment: Yes it is 4.13.2.  Both CSS and JS.  I will put the web code in my question, and I will try to get the server code, although it is kinda of a monster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the bug report! The problem: I implemented in free jqGrid restoring the filter toolbar based on the current filter. The feature works only in case of `stringResult: true` mode, when jqGrid send all information about the filter inside of one `filters` parameter (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options)), like in case of usage advanced searching (`multipleSearch: true`).

The usage of the new feature with legacy searching following to cleaning the filter toolbar. It's the bug, which I fixed (see [the commit](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/ef0fe3d281a71693a3db1f08ace0a86223c74f38)) in the current code of free jqGrid. If you need to use version 4.13.2 then you can add `loadFilterDefaults: false` option which will remove restoring the filter:

```
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { loadFilterDefaults: false });
```

Comment: the `loadFilterDefaults: false` fixed the problem for me for know.  With the new version I will remove this.